# List item doesn't removed

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox

I have 2 buttons and a `ListBox`. When I click the 1st button it is supposed to remove the selected item from `ListBox` but it doesn't - the `ListBox` stays the same. What is wrong with the code?

```
static List<string> Blist = new List<string>();
public int x;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Blist = (List<string>)Session["items"];

    if (Blist != null)
    {
        ListBox1.Items.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < Blist.Count; i++)
            ListBox1.Items.Add(Blist[i]);
    }
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    x= ListBox1.SelectedIndex;

    if (x >= 0)
    {
        ListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(x);
        string m = Blist[x];
        Blist.Remove(m);

        Session["items"] = null;
        Session["items"] = Blist;
    }
}

protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["items"] = null;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When your page posts back (When the button is clicked) the Page_Load handler fires again. When it does this it repopulates your list. To prevent this you need to check if its a page post back, or the initial load. You do this by checking if `Page.IsPostBack` is true or false. If its true it means that the page is being posted back (by a button click or whatever). If its not true it means its the initial loading of the page.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      Blist = (List<string>)Session["items"];

      if (!Page.IsPostBack)
      {

         if (Blist != null)
         {
             ListBox1.Items.Clear();
             for (int i = 0; i < Blist.Count; i++)
                 ListBox1.Items.Add(Blist[i]);
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: @Charles For the exact same reason the other answer with the same suggestion was downvoted, and with the explination in that answer's comments.  I didn't see the need to re-post them here considering Steve is reading that thread as well.

Comment: haha... I write this answer I get -1, you write it and +3. +1

Comment: Thank you very much IsPostBack help me alot (:

Comment: @AseelNasser You give me correct answer and then take it away and give it to the guy with the incorrect answer? lol....